# Android: Change Bitmap image displayed on Canvas

Tags: java, android

I am drawing a bitmap in my onDraw and want to be able to change that image when a user clicks on a certain part of the screen.  I display the image like this...

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mallMap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawLines(pts, paint);}
```

then in my onTouch method I'd like to be able to redraw a different bitmap

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    Canvas.drawBitmap(lowerLeft, 0, 0, null);
    return false;}
```

is something like this possible?  I need to stick with a canvas and am not sure how I would got about doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing the value of mallMap to a new Bitmap in the onTouchEvent and then calling [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) on the view to cause the onDraw to be run again. You should not have to reference the canvas outside of the onDraw using this method.